# Angular 10 Upgrade: Why use @Directive() instead of @Component() for abstract (component) classes?

Tags: angular, angular10

I recently upgraded my Angular app from v9 to v10.

I noticed that undecorated classes are not supported anymore. See [here](https://v9.angular.io/guide/deprecations#undecorated-base-classes-using-angular-features)

So during `ng upgrade` my abstract components without decorates have been changed to have a `@Directive()` decoratror.

For example

```
export abstract class AbstractFormControl implements ControlValueAccessor { ... }
```

was changed into

```
@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractFormControl implements ControlValueAccessor { ... }
```

Why does Angular use `@Directive`. Wouldn't `@Component` be a better way because the class is rather a Component than a Directive? What was the intention?

Comment: A component is essentially a directive with template. When the base class doesn't have an associated template, it makes more sense to decorate it as a directive rather than a component. If you need to know _why_ this change is required, you could see [here](https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes#why-is-this-migration-necessary).

Answer (score 5):

Component requires you to specify `template` or `templateUrl`, which cannot be used with
an abstract class.

As mentioned in the comments - Component is a special type of Directive. So it is okay to inherit from an abstract Directive.

Comment: It looks to me like `@Component({ template: '' })` works fine as a decorator for abstract classes in Angular 12, even though `@Directive` may be preferred.

Comment: I don't know what is the impact of that - does it mean you would be able to route to it for example. The recommended way from Angular team was to use Directive and therefore the migration changed added @Directive